# Dispatch an action from container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to react-redux and i want to dispatch an action from container to component. Here is my code :

**Container** :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import addCountryComponent from '../../views/Country/AddCountry'
import { addCountry } from '../../actions/countryActions'


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addCountry:(country) => dispatch(addCountry(country))
  }
}


const CountryContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(addCountryComponent)
export default CountryContainer;
```

**AddCountry Component :**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class AddCountry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
asdas
      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default AddCountry;
```

and **Action file**

```
import { ADD_COUNTRY } from './names'


export function addCountry(payload) {
  console.log(payload, "actions")
  return {
    type: ADD_COUNTRY,
    payload,
  }
}
```

I can't see `addCountry` as a props, am i missing something ?

Comment: what's `Form.create()` in your `AddCountry`

Comment: That `Form.create()` is probably intercepting the props `connect` adds

Comment: it's for antd library, will remove it now

Comment: just remove it from the code and still can't see it

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally render `<AddCountry />` component instead of `< CountryContainer />` ?

Comment: in the route.js this url `/add/country` will render <AddCountry /> not the container

Comment: Thanks @UğurKaya, that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you mentioned in the comment you should link your container to your route file.

that means your container gets called when a browser open this `/add/country`

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      addCountry: (country) => dispatch({ type: ADD_COUNTRY ,country})
    }}
TO  used it on click event 
you should make  add reducer for this app
example
const balance =(state={country:""},action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case ADD_COUNTRY:  return{ country: action.country;}
this.props.addCountry(country)
```

Answer (score 0):

This because of `mapDispatchToProps` auto-add property `addCountry` to your addCountryComponent.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    // component that using this function will auto have addCountry in props of component 
    addCountry:(country) => dispatch(addCountry(country))
  }
}

// this addCountryComponent using mapDispatchToProps so it have addCountry in props
const CountryContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(addCountryComponent)
export default CountryContainer;
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using `bindActionCreators` function of Redux?

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
  addCountry: addCountry,
}, dispatch);
```

Comment: should i import the container somewhere ?